# Failed to execute child process "xterm"

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+

I updated my Pi yesterday.
 Afterwards my own sh program, which is for switching audio-outputs stopped starting with the error message Failed to execute child process "xterm".
The programm uses the ***#!/bin/bash*** start command.
Its still possible to run it when calling it directly from the command line, but executing by clicking on it isn't.
So I installed xterm, but when starting the script it opens in a weird window with strange font, font-size and so on.
What's the matter?

Comment: Did you reboot after the upgrade?

Comment: Yep. I did that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I did was placing a sympbolic link which retains the execution code reference:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/lxterminal /usr/bin/xterm
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue until I ran this command into the terminal: `sudo apt-get install xterm` for some reason after the update xterm went missing by itself. Before you run it you might want to delete xterm first if it's already installed by running `sudo apt-get delete xterm`

Comment: The `apt-get` program does not have a command `delete`. Do you mean command `remove` or `purge`, maybe with option `--autoremove`? You should update your answer.

Answer (score 1):

1) Open Terminal

> Click on the Terminal Window.

2) `cd /usr/bin`

> sets target directory (actually changes directory.) for cp (copy) command.

3) `sudo cp lxterminal xterm`

> It makes another copy of "lxterminal" and re-names it to "xterm" (old terminal) so you can use both lxterminal and xterm command to start terminal.

Problem Solved Enjoy.

Comment: Welcome ExTremTR! Please edit your answer to show what those commands do and why your answer fixes the OP question?

Answer (score 0):

After days of being unable to solve this problem, I tried the super trivial approach, to just copy the file **lxterminal** from **/usr/bin/** and rename it to **xterm** and BOOM, problem solved.

Comment: Then no soup for you! And by soup I mean `xterm` updates.